# sum values of two csv files and results to a new file

Tags: python

I need some help and don't know how to start with it.

Basically, i have two csv input files (coming from 2 different nodes) and  would like to sum the values with the result going to elasticsearch..

Any help is greatly appreciated...

CSV1

```
node    link    rate-in rate-out
node1   link1   10  20
node1   link2   30  50
node1   link3   40  60
```

CSV2

```
node    link    rate-in rate-out
node2   link1   20  10
node2   link2   50  70
node2   link3   80  40
```

Result --> create elasticsearch index

```
node    link    rate-in rate-out
allnode link1   30  30
allnode link2   80  120
allnode link3   120 100
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has good support for reading and manipulating CSV files.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv('csv1.csv'),
        pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')
    ])

    result=df.groupby('link', as_index=False).sum()
    result['node'] = 'allnode'

    result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Where csv1.csv is:

```
    node,link,rate-in,rate-out
    node1,link1,10,20
    node1,link2,30,50
    node1,link3,40,60
```

And csv2.csv is:

```
    node,link,rate-in,rate-out
    node2,link1,20,10
    node2,link2,50,70
    node2,link3,80,40
```

The result.csv file will contain:

```
    link,rate-in,rate-out,node
    link1,30,30,allnode
    link2,80,120,allnode
    link3,120,100,allnode
```

If you want to reorder the columns you can do that by providing an order list

```
    result[[
        'node','link','rate-in','rate-out'
    ]].to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: small question, in the result.csv the node column is put at the end.. is it possible to put this as the first column?

Answer (score 1):

After importing your CSV as dataframes into python

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'node':['node1', 'node1', 'node1'], 'link': ['link1', 'link2', 'link3'], 'rate-in': [10, 30, 40], 'rate-out': [20, 50, 60]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'node':['node2', 'node2', 'node2'], 'link': ['link1', 'link2', 'link3'], 'rate-in': [20, 50, 80], 'rate-out': [10, 70, 40]})

result = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).groupby('link').agg({'node': lambda x : 'allNodes', 'rate-in': 'sum', 'rate-out': 'sum'}).reset_index(drop=False)
result
```

Output :

```
link    node    rate-in rate-out
0   link1   allNodes    30  30
1   link2   allNodes    80  120
2   link3   allNodes    120 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the in-build `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open("CSV1.csv") as csvfile_1, open("CSV2.csv") as csvfile_2:
    reader_1 = csv.DictReader(csvfile_1)
    reader_2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile_2)
    result = []
    data_1 = {"{}_{}".format(row["node"], row["link"]): (int(row["rate-in"]), int(row["rate-out"])) for row in reader_1}
    for row in reader_2:
        key = "{}_{}".format(row["node"], row["link"])
        if key in data_1:
            rate_in, rate_out = data_1[key]
            result.append({"node": "allnode", "link": row["link"], "rate-in": rate_in + int(row["rate-in"]),  "rate-out": rate_out + int(row["rate-out"])})

with open("outcsv.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['node', 'link', 'rate-in', 'rate-out'])  
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import sys

nodeList = {}

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as csv1,open('file2.csv', 'r') as csv2: 
    # creating a csv reader object 
    csvreader1 = csv.reader(csv1,delimiter='\t')
    next(csvreader1)
    csvreader2 = csv.reader(csv2,delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csvreader2)

    for row in csvreader1:
        # print(len(row),row)

        nodeList[row[1]] = ['allnode',row[1],int(row[2]),int(row[3])]

    for row in csvreader2:
        if row[1] in nodeList:
            nodeList[row[1]][2]+=int(row[2])
            nodeList[row[1]][3]+=int(row[3])
        else:
            nodeList[row[1]] = ['allnode',row[1],int(row[2]),int(row[3])]

with open('outfile.csv','wb') as out:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(out,delimiter='\t')

    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    for v in nodeList.values():
        csvwriter.writerow(v)
```

change the values in file1.csv,file2.csv for first and second file
and outfile.csv to required output file

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is large, you can read directly from your csv file and add the values of the columns you need for the output instead of explicitly hardcoding each value.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv', header = 0) # place your csv1 in df1
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv', header = 0) # place your csv2 in df2

rate_in_1 = df1.iloc[:,2].values.tolist() #store the values of the 3rd column from csv1 to a list
rate_out_1 = df1.iloc[:,3].values.tolist() #store the values of the 4th column from csv1 to a list

rate_in_2 = df2.iloc[:,2].values.tolist() #store the values of the 3rd column from csv1 to a list
rate_out_2 = df2.iloc[:,3].values.tolist() #store the values of the 4th column from csv1 to a list

rate_in_total = [x+y for x, y in zip(rate_in_1, rate_in_2)] # add the values of 2 rate in lists into rate_in_total list
rate_out_total = [x+y for x, y in zip(rate_out_1, rate_out_2] # add the values of 2 rate out lists into rate_out_total list


#Now to output/concatenate this into 1 DataFrame:

final_df = pandas.Dataframe()
final_df['Node'] = ['allnode' for x in rate_in_total]
final_df['Link'] = df1.iloc[:,1].values.tolist()
final_df['rate-in'] = rate_in_total
final_df['rate-out'] = rate_out_total
```

If you want to write your `final_df` into a csv file, just simply use the `.to_csv()` method from pandas and you're good to go.

Hope this helps :))